# React Native FlatList - Only renders the first item

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, mobile-application

I am new at React Native and struggling with the FlatList component. I currently have two functions, inside function "ItemHolders", I have a flatlist that calls my second function, "WardrobeSubsection". The problem is that, even though inside my WardrobeSubsection function both subsections are displayed in the terminal (due to the console log), only one is appearing on my screen. How can I solve this?
Here is the data I try to pass to flatlist inside ItemHolders:

```
const [itemData] = useState<Items | null>({
    title: 'Tops',
    subcategory: [
      {
        id: '12',
        title: 'Tank Tops',
        item: [{id: '4'}, {id: '5'}],
      },
      {
        id: '14',
        title: 'Sweaters',
        item: [{id: '6'}, {id: '7'}],
      },
    ],
  });
```

Here is the flatlist (I pass itemData.subcategory):

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setShowFullSection(!showFullSection)}
        style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{itemData?.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {showFullSection && (
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          data={itemData?.subcategory}
          renderItem={({item}) => <WardrobeSubsection subcategory={item} />}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

The WardrobeSubsection:

```
const WardrobeSubsection: React.FC<SubcategoryProps> = props => {
  console.log('Subcategory data:', props.subcategory);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{props.subcategory.title}</Text>
      </View>
      {props.subcategory.item.map(items => (
        <Text key={items.id}>{items.id}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

The output of the console log:
LOG  `Subcategory data: {"id": "12", "item": [{"id": "4"}, {"id": "5"}], "title": "Tank Tops"}`
LOG  `Subcategory data: {"id": "14", "item": [{"id": "6"}, {"id": "7"}], "title": "Sweaters"}`
However, it is displayed as:
[displayed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yH4W.png)
I was expecting to see both Sweaters and Tank Tops.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Something wrong with styles? Without styles the list renders just fine.

Comment: @user18309290 thank you so much! I accidentally put height 100% to WardrobeSection; thus, it only showed the first element. :D